# men who [ hated / had hated ] him

Tags: meaning, past-perfect

> There was a touch of paternal contempt in it, even toward people he liked—and there were men at New Haven who had hated his guts. (from The Great Gatsby)

What's the difference between those? Would the latter mean there were several more cases people hated him in various times and places?

Comment: He doesn't say whether the men at New Haven had hated his guts at various times or at one particular time. The use of "had" suggests that they they no longer hate him. Perhaps their hatred simply wore off, or perhaps he moved away. If Fitzgerald had said, "there were men at New Haven who hated his guts" it would suggest they _still_ hated him.

Comment: The **had hated** is preceded by a past tense: There was. The past perfect ** always precedes**  something in the simple past or past continuous, either express or implied. When he **called me**, I **had already eaten** dinner. Think of the simple or continuous as what stops the action given in the past perfect.

Comment: I doubt it would have made any difference if Fitzgerald had written *and there **had been** men at New Haven who **hated** his guts.* But as a competent writer, he wouldn't have been likely to use Past Perfect for *both* verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference in meaning. Writing "had hated" seems more precise grammatically, placing the situation in the past, without continuation to the present.

The simple past tense ("...men at New Haven hated his guts.") could suggest that the men who were at New Haven (Yale) *then* "hated his guts" then and now. But that is not actually said.

In a simple statement about what someone did, there is no practical difference in meaning between past and past perfect:

After high school, he had gone to Yale. After high school, he went to Yale.